# Change Base Content Type of Content Type

Tags: 2010, content-type

In Sharepoint 2010, is there any way to change the parent (or base) type of a Content Type after the relationship has been established?

Comment: Is the new Content Type already in use in the site?

Comment: @Dave Wise - It isn't in use on the site yet. If it was though, I take it is a no-go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the way that ContentTypeIDs are created, I would be very surprised if there was anything in the API that let you do this.  However, since the Content Type is not in use yet, you should probably simply delete the current one and then recreate it based on the desired base type.

A Best Practice is to create your own Content Type derived from one of the SharePoint types and then use that as the base content type for all other custom content types you create.  This lets you optionally add new columns to the Base Type without having to break all of your custom content types.

Comment: Are there any sharepoint types that don't have any columns that I have to show? It looks like List Content Types -> Item just has title, but I don't even want to have that if I can avoid it.

Comment: You can mark the field as hidden for that content type in the UI.  If you are creating your content types in Visual Studio then you can use the RemoveFieldRef option (http://panvega.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/custom-content-type-without-title/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to support that kind of operation. I would stay away from anything which is not supported by SharePoint APIs. The Parent property of content type is Read-only so you cannot change the relatioship.